# Load a HTML page when I click ENTER while the item is selected using Keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this keyboard navigation on my website.

I am trying to load a different html file when it is selected.

What I want is actually it loads `item1.html` when I click <kbd>ENTER</kbd> while `Item 1` is selected. It loads `item2.html` when I click <kbd>ENTER</kbd> while `Item 2` is selected. How do I use the JavaScript.

Any help or links to explanations would be great. Thank you!

The code I am using is the same as this :

```js
(function($, document) {
  'use strict';

  var items = $('#list').children();

  function selectItem(item) {
    item.addClass('selected')
      .attr('aria-selected', 'true')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('selected')
      .attr('aria-selected', 'false');
  }

  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
    var key = event.which,
      direction = null,
      position = null,
      item = null;

    switch (key) {
      case 35: // End
        position = 'last';
        break;
      case 36: // Home
        position = 'first';
        break;
      case 38: // Key up
        direction = 'prev';
        break;
      case 40: // Key down
        direction = 'next';
        break;
    }

    if (position) {
      item = items[position]();
    } else if (direction) {
      item = items.filter('.selected')[direction]();
    }

    if (item) {
      selectItem(item);
    }
  });

  $('#list a').click(function() {
    selectItem($(this).closest('li'));
    return false;
  });

  selectItem(items.first());

})(jQuery, document);
```

```css
body {
  width: 30em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font: 81.25%/1.5 Lato, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
}

kbd {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#list {
  width: 12em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#list a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #393;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#list li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#list li.selected a {
  background-color: #c22;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Click on this demo to give it focus.</p>
  <p>Click to select an item or use <kbd>key up</kbd>, <kbd>key down</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd>, or <kbd>end</kbd>.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Do you know the basics of jQuery? Selectors and events at least? You could piggyback off the code in that example and add a case for the enter/return key (13). Do a little research and try writing some code of your own. We will be here to help when you have a specific coding question and a sample of your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple to accomplish.

Just add an event listener to the document like:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown',(ev)=>{
  if(ev.keyCode === 13) {
    switch(ev.target.id) {
      case 'item2':
        window.open('./item2.html')
      
    }
  }
});
```

In the above code, event listener is fired for each keydown event on the document, but we are filtering it for only for ENTER press event and when that ENTER event occurs on an element with the specified ID, we then open a new page as a result.

Hope this helps.

## EDIT

I have made a plunker which does the same. You can check it here [Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/Sg4XJQxSZhtqXrEgyFMB/)

Comment: Its not working, @Rohit. I tried to add an ID for my item. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few lines of code for your requirement

```js
// find elements
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var selectedPage=$("#nav-form input:checked").val();
       if(selectedPage === 'facebook'){
       
        location.href = "https://www.facebook.com";
       }else if(selectedPage === 'twitter'){
       
        location.href = "https://www.twitter.com";
       }else{
        location.href = "https://www.instagram.com";
       }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner">
<form id="nav-form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked value="facebook">Facebbok
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="twitter">Twitter
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="instagram">Instagram
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: the code its no working for me, is it because of the input? This is how i modify it.

Comment: <script>
 $(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var selectedPage=$("#list li.selected").val();
       if(selectedPage === 'facebook'){
       
        location.href = "https://www.facebook.com";
       }else if(selectedPage === 'twitter'){
       
        location.href = "https://www.twitter.com";
       }else{
        location.href = "https://www.instagram.com";
       }
    }
});
 
 
 </script>

Comment: I didn't see your code snippet, as I assumed that your selecting radio input, so that is why I have given the above. if it is in li , how you will get value. var selectedPage=$("#list li.selected").val() ?.

Comment: Its is possible to call ID instead of Value?

Comment: Still no solved. I tried your Javascript. No matter what I select, it only loads instagram page.

Comment: did you run the same code snippet..  I checked it couple of times except first time it will load the page what you will select.

Comment: Yah, after I applied on my code, it only load instagram page but yours is working fine.